# Exception has occurred: urllib.error.URLError <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

Tags: python, urllib, conda

i'm having an issue with this code.

```
my_url = 'https://google.com' 
uClient = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url) 
page_html = uClient.read() 
uClient.close()
```

When I try to run it with conda, it give me

```
'Exception has occurred: urllib.error.URLError <urlopen error unknown url type: https>'
```

But if I run it using python compiler it works just fine.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Please supply more information about your environment: a) OS: Linux, Windows, MacOS, other? b) python and conda versions.